# UILabel in a grouped table view's header doesn't wrap text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel, word-wrap

I have a label whose text is longer that the table view's header containing it, so I want the label to be split into N lines according to the width available. This is my code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1) {
    UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    [wrapper setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"This is supposed to be a very long text that may fill several lines", @"");
    [textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [wrapper addSubview:textLabel];

    return wrapper;
  }
  else
    return nil;
}
```

However, the label is in a single line and I can't see the end of the text. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the delegate method `heightForHeaderInSection`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section ==1)
        return 100;
    else
        return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1) {

  NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"This is supposed to be a very long text that may fill several lines", @"");;

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, 999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
    frame.size = size;

    UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [wrapper setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"This is supposed to be a very long text that may fill several lines", @"");
    [textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [wrapper addSubview:textLabel];

    return wrapper;
  }
  else
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if you want to support iOS below 6.0

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

As UILineBreakModeWordWrap deprecated now.

otherwise use this

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set size of label as text in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *text;
    CGSize textViewSize;
    int width = 270;
    textViewSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0]
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(textViewSize.height, 44.0f);
    return height;

}
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath write this

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    textViewSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0]
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)
                        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
    //  /  CGFloat height = MAX(textViewSize.height, 44.0f);

    //    if (!lblParameter){
    //        lblParameter = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];}
    CGFloat height = MAX(textViewSize.height, 44.0f);
    [lblParameter setText:text];
    [lblParameter setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0]];
    [lblParameter setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0,width,height)];
    [[cell contentView] addSubview:lblParameter];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need caculate the height of uilabel this height equal font size * numberline

Answer (score 0):

It seems that wrapping / formatting will not work on a label inside the header view - presumably because it's inheriting defaults from somewhere. So, a simple solution, which AFAIK breaks no laws, is to put the label inside a view inside the header view.

Using the storyboard, drag a view to the table view controller (above your prototype cell).
**Add a second view to this view.**
Add the label to this second view. Make sure both views and label are tall enough to allow for multiple lines of text. In the label's attributes, set Lines to 0 and Line Breaks to Word Wrap.
Wrapping will now work as expected.